# agregar input y select dinamicos

Tags: javascript, jquery

hola amigos tengo un archivo .js el cual me permite agregar filas dinámicas y me funciona perfectamente, pero mi problema surje que ahora estoy utilizando 1 input y 2 select dinámicos que cargan valores desde la base de datos, como tendría que hacer para agregar esos dos select en el archivo.js, ya que nunca me a tocada de esa forma, pero como dice el dicho siempre hay una primera vez.

**este es mi archivo.js el cual funciona perfectamente pero solo es con input**

```
var inputs = 3;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#agregar').on('click', function() {
if (inputs == 6) {
  return false;
}
inputs = inputs + 1;
if ($('#alumno' + inputs + '').length > 0) {
  $('#alumno' + inputs + '').show();
} else {

$('.inputs').append('<div id="alumno'+inputs+'"><div class="input-field col s12 m4"><input id="cedula" type="text" name="cedula[]" autocomplete="off" title="Cedula!" required/><label for="cedula">Cédula:</label></div><div class="input-field col s12 m4"><input id="nombres" type="text" name="nombres" autocomplete="off" title="Nombres!" required/><label for="nombres">Nombres:</label></div><div class="input-field col s12 m4"><input id="apellidos" type="text" name="apellidos" autocomplete="off" title="Apellidos!" required/><label for="nombres">Apellidos:</label></div></div>');

}

$('#quitar').fadeIn();
if (inputs == 6) {
  $('#agregar').fadeOut();

}
});
$('#quitar').on('click', function() {
if (inputs == 3) {
  return false;
}
$('#alumno' + inputs + '').hide();
inputs = inputs - 1;
$('#agregar').fadeIn();
if (inputs == 3) {
  $('#quitar').fadeOut();
}
});
});
```

**estos son los dos select que quiero agregar en el archivo .js**

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m4">
<select name="id_cuentas" id="id_cuentas" required/>
<option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de Cuenta:</option>
<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY id_cuentas");
while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $linea['id_cuentas[]'] ;?>"><?php echo 
$linea['cuentas'] ;?></option>
<?php
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 </div>


 <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
 <select name="id_bancos" id="id_bancos"  required/>
 <option value="" disabled selected>Banco Destino:</option>
 <?php
 $consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM bancos ORDER BY id_bancos");
 while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $linea['id_bancos[]'] ;?>"><?php echo $linea['bancos'] ;?></option>
 <?php
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Si el codigo php no es necesario para tu pregunta podrias elimniarlo y asi clarificar mas tu pregunta? Si es asi elimina tambien las etiquetas `php` y `pdo`

Comment: el problema es como haría para meter esos dos select en el archivo .js en el ejemplo lo puse con input, pero en este caso necesito hacerlo con select dinamicos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te cuento como lo hice en su momento:
En vez de usar php incrustado lo que hice fue preparar un archivo.php que me daba el resultado de la consulta en json y con $.post enviaba la consulta sql y asi obtienes la info para manejarla con javascript
Saludos.